# _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "table"

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, installation, tktable

I tried to use tktable package to create table and show my data.
However, I could not make it work.

```
import Tkinter
import tktable

root = Tkinter.Tk()
table = tktable.Table(root, rows=10, cols=4)
table.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

I got error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/jgou/PycharmProjects/mmt-autobench/autobench/test/test.py", 
line 520, in <module> table = Table(root, rows=10, cols=4)
File "C:\Users\jgou\PycharmProjects\mmtautobench\autobench\inst\tktable.py", 
line 135, in __init__tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, 'table', kw)
File "C:\Users\jgou\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\libtk\Tkinter.py", 
line 2096, in __init__(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "table"
```

I searched online and could you solve the issue, please suggest and help. It made me crazy. It should be very easy. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you get an error _like_ what you wrote, or is that the exact error?

Comment: It is the exact error.

Comment: Here is the error log:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jgou/PycharmProjects/mmt-autobench/autobench/test/test.py", line 520, in <module>
    table = tktable.Table(root, rows=10, cols=4)
  File "C:\Users\jgou\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\tktable.py", line 135, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, 'table', kw)
  File "C:\Users\jgou\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2096, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "table"

Comment: Please don't put tracebacks in the comment section.  You can [edit]  your question to add additional information.